# JavaScript async function not executed in module

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-modules

According to the [compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/), Firefox 54 supports async/await but in the following code, the asynchronous function never gets executed, even though it does not even wait for anything. Is the compatibility table wrong or is there a mistake in the code?

```html
<html>
<body>
<script type="module">
function helloSync()
{
 alert("sync: This alert always happens");
}

async function helloAsync()
{
 alert("async: This alert never happens");
}

helloSync();
helloAsync();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just tested it on FF 52 and it's working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/w8dnhkyn/ Are you sure you're on FF 54?

Comment: @shotor: The problem only occurs when it is in a module. Yes, I am on Firefox 54.0.

Comment: Check, I'll get back to you

Comment: @shotor: Thanks! But it won't work on Firefox 52 because modules only work from 54 onwards and only with the flag dom.moduleScripts.enabled=true.

Comment: Yeah, I'm updating it now. Thanks for the flag comment, I wouldn't have known that!

Comment: *A good chunk of this spec is out of date and is undergoing revision to realign it with Service Worker, the JS Realms API, and the dynamic import() feature.* are you shure you want to use that already?

Comment: @Jonasw: In that case I guess I will refactor my code using promises. I thought it being in FF 52+ means that it is stable already.

Comment: @konrad höffner theres no such thing like *stable* thanks to IE. The only real js working everywhere is basically ES3 with many polyfills :/

Comment: @jonaw: I plan to transpile it with babel for production anyways, so I only need to get it to work natively at my development browser.